# How can i create (n) label in xamarin?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

In my project; I have so many json file from web. And inside json file have campaign datas. But that data numbers is always changing. For example in first json it have 5 data and other json have 15. So I need create labels for that datas. For example if in the json file have 5 campaign data , i need create 5. İf it have 10 then i need create 10. Like this. So how can i make it ? I input json files and its works correctly i just need learn how can i create , position  N label in xamarin ?  Thanks for your help! <3

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [how-to-ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to improve your question and help us to understand your problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

just create them and add them to some layout container, like this

```
var stack = new StackLayout();

foreach(var l in LabelData())
{
  stack.Children.Add(new Label { Text = l.SomeProperty });
}
```